# Creating a presentation table with nested(?) levels

Tags: r, dplyr, gt

I have a large dataset containing many nested subcategories, and I would like to make a table of mean values. I've been trying to figure it out in `gt` but I am stuck. using the palmerpenguins data for this example:

```
library(gt)
library(tidyverse)
library(palmerpenguins)
library(markdown)

penguins%>%
  group_by(island, species) %>%
  summarize_at(
    .vars= c("bill_length_mm",
             "bill_depth_mm",
             "flipper_length_mm",
             "body_mass_g"
    ),
    .funs= ~ mean(.,na.rm=TRUE)
  )%>%
  gt(rowname_col = "species", "island")%>%
  tab_header(
    title = md("The *penguins* dataset"),
    subtitle = md("three years of data on penguins on on ***three islands***")
  )%>% 
  cols_label(
    bill_length_mm=md("Bill Length, <br>mm"),
    bill_depth_mm=md("Bill Depth, <br>mm"),
    flipper_length_mm=md("Flipper Length, <br>mm"),
    body_mass_g=md("Body Mass, <br>kg")
  )%>%
  opt_align_table_header(align="left")%>%
  fmt_number(columns = "body_mass_g", scale_by= 1/1000)
```

creates this table.
[image]

I would like, in this example, to also be able to get the means per `island` row as well as `species`.
Ultimately, I'm trying to make a table very similar to this one (Soininen et al. 2013), but with actually more nested levels/subcategories.
[image]

Is there a different package i should be using than `gt`? should i be going a whole different route rather than expecting there to be a table packge that can do this? also please correct me if i'm using the phrase nested incorrectly in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another solution using kableExtra.  You'll have to download a version from github to pick up a fix that collapses the repeating row values.

```
devtools::install_github(repo="haozhu233/kableExtra", ref="a6af5c0")
library(kableExtra)

a<-penguins%>% 
    group_by(island,species,sex)%>% 
    summarize_at( .vars=c("bill_length_mm"), 
                  .funs=~mean(.,na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
    mutate(sort = 3) 

b<-penguins%>%
    group_by(island,species) %>% 
    summarize_at( .vars=c("bill_length_mm"), 
                  .funs=~mean(.,na.rm=TRUE)) %>% 
    mutate(sex="", sort = 2) %>% 
    select(island,species,sex,everything()) 

c<-penguins %>% 
    group_by(island) %>% 
    summarize_at( .vars=c("bill_length_mm"), 
                  .funs=~mean(.,na.rm=TRUE)) %>% 
    mutate(species="", sex = "", sort = 1) %>% 
    select(island,species,everything()) 


rbind(a,b,c) %>% 
    arrange(island, species, sort) %>% 
    select(-sort) %>%
    kbl() %>%
    kable_paper(full_width = F) %>%
    column_spec(1, bold = T) %>%
    collapse_rows(columns = 1:3, valign = "top")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The data is really just coming from your grouping. gt is not doing any aggregation. These are the exact figures you are getting in the table just with enhanced row labels.

```
penguins%>%
  group_by(island, species) %>%
  summarize_at(
    .vars= c("bill_length_mm",
             "bill_depth_mm",
             "flipper_length_mm",
             "body_mass_g"
    ),
    .funs= ~ mean(.,na.rm=TRUE)
  )

island    species   bill_length_mm bill_depth_mm flipper_length_mm body_mass_g
  <fct>     <fct>              <dbl>         <dbl>             <dbl>       <dbl>
1 Biscoe    Adelie              39.0          18.4              189.       3710.
2 Biscoe    Gentoo              47.5          15.0              217.       5076.
3 Dream     Adelie              38.5          18.3              190.       3688.
4 Dream     Chinstrap           48.8          18.4              196.       3733.
5 Torgersen Adelie              39.0          18.4              191.       3706.
```

So, if you manipulate the groupings further, you may be able to get what you are looking for. As a first step I group the data based on island and species as you have done. Then I create a data set grouped just on island. I add back in a "species" field to that second data set so the fields match. That allows me to then bind the two together. Then arrange so the rows are in the right order. From there run it through gt.

```
a<-penguins%>% 
    group_by(island,species,sex)%>% 
    summarize_at( .vars=c("bill_length_mm"), 
                  .funs=~mean(.,na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
    mutate(sort = 3) 

b<-penguins%>%
    group_by(island,species) %>% 
    summarize_at( .vars=c("bill_length_mm"), 
                  .funs=~mean(.,na.rm=TRUE)) %>% 
    mutate(sex="**", sort = 2) %>% 
    select(island,species,sex,everything()) 

c<-penguins %>% 
    group_by(island) %>% 
    summarize_at( .vars=c("bill_length_mm"), 
                  .funs=~mean(.,na.rm=TRUE)) %>% 
    mutate(species="**", sex = "**", sort = 1) %>% 
    select(island,species,everything()) 

rbind(a,b,c) %>% 
    arrange(island, species, sort) %>% 
    select(-sort) %>%
    gt(rowname_col= "species", "island")
```

Is this a bit closer to what you are looking for?

[image]

Comment: It's definitely closer.... but I need the means per island to be on the islands row. Also I played around with adding a third grouping (sex, in this example), and that comes up with ```Error in if (simplify) { : argument is not interpretable as logical```, so it seems that subsetting into 2 groups is the max.

Comment: `a<-penguins%>%
group_by(island,species,sex)%>%
summarize_at(
.vars=c("bill_length_mm"),
.funs=~mean(.,na.rm=TRUE))

b<-penguins%>%group_by(island,species) %>%
summarize_at(
.vars=c("bill_length_mm"),
.funs=~mean(.,na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
mutate(sex="") %>%
select(island,species,sex,everything())

c<-penguins %>% group_by(island) %>%
summarize_at(
.vars=c("bill_length_mm"),
.funs=~mean(.,na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
mutate(species="") %>%
mutate(sex="")%>%
select(island,species,everything())


rbind(a,b,c)%>%
arrange("island","species","sex") %>%
gt(rowname_col="species","island","sex")`

Comment: I was able to run this with 3 levels.  I've updated my example for the three levels and also added in a sort key to help bring the summarized values to the top instead of the bottom. I don't see that gt is going to allow you to put a Summary Cell in the row with a Row Group Label which seems to be what you are after. I've got it to the top Row Label.